# Why is a question on Inkjet refill Off Topic for Superuser?

Tags: support, closed-questions

[How do I refill a CD887A inkjet cartridge?](https://superuser.com/questions/992005/how-do-i-refill-sponge-based-inkjet-cartridges?noredirect=1#comment1368178_992005)

1. My question is on Inkjet Printers and how to refill them with ink(a very common operation).
2. [The Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_hardware) of Computer Hardware includes printers.

   > Output devices display information in a human readable form. Such devices could include *printers*, speakers, monitors or a Braille embosser."
3. The Super User on topic link states: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

   Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
   **computer hardware**, computer software, or

I contacted Super User [Help Center](https://superuser.com/contact) using this link and they asked me to post here.

> if you have a question about a site, the best place to ask is on Meta, the site for questions and issues about the main site. "

Comment: You started with one question, and then kept on asking more and more questions which go all over the place

Comment: that's not a topic issue is it? they've marked it as: "put on hold as off-topic by ..." The scope is defined here: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic Additionally I can't just state "How do I refill my inkjet cartridge CAxyz"? That's perfectly valid Q, but someone else will ask "How do i refill CAabcd?" etc. I need to flesh out my question and provide opportunities for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I also voted on the question and will explain my thinking.  At the time I read it, I thought that how to refill cartridges was too far removed from the site's focus, in much the same way as these would be: how to manufacturer your own cartridge, how to make your own ink, how to make your own paper, how to build your own printer.  Manufacturing, remanufacturing, product design and development, etc., are different specialties from using and solving problems with computer hardware and software.  However, I accept Random's answer that it's on topic.

Comment: In an effort to avoid having my comment being quoted, I deleted my comment, the comment wasn't of high enough quality to be quoted..  If I wanted to be quoted I would have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Inkjet cartridges are on topic, and how to refill them as well.

What your question ended up being was too broad and should have been closed as such.

In a lot of cases how you you refill it, it depends on what cartridge or model.

The off topic parts are:

- asking if the seller is legitimate
- where else to get information about rolling your own inks

So try and bring it back by focussing on refilling a specific model because you do not want answers coming in that don't work for your model if that's going to be an issue. Who knows unless you tell us.

A way too generic question is as a bad as a severely narrow one (think obsolete/outdated cartridge for a printer sold only in East Germany).

Comment: I **did not** ask if the seller was legitimate: "*Also, **the chemicals involved in these inks are Pyrrolidone and Pentanediol** - so **how does one detect** if the guy selling the refill inks has done his duty be me? Someone did point out that gas chromatography was one such way.

Comment: "so how does one detect if the guy selling the refill inks has done his duty be me?" is an ambiguous sentence which can refer to either the seller or the person preparing the cartridges