# Is this general printer refill question appropriate?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I asked a general question regarding refilling toner in laser printers. Is this question appropriate?

[When refilling toner, why only to half capacity?](https://superuser.com/questions/994142/when-refilling-toner-why-only-to-half-capacity)

- SuperUser is appropriate for computer support questions, right? 
   (I understand that Hardware Recommendations is not.)
- Question is general enough to be useful to more people, right?
- Would this question be appropriate for Skeptics site instead?

Comment: This is similar to [this question on refilling inkjet cartridges](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/10889/why-is-a-question-on-inkjet-refill-off-topic-for-superuser).  From random's answer, the subject of refills is on-topic.  People unfamiliar with refilling toner might object to the "why only half capacity" as opinion based.  However, all toner refills involve filling less than full for the reason given in Tyson's comment, so the question is factually answerable.  I suspect the close votes are because people had the same reaction I had on the inkjet refills before seeing random's answer.